# Vauxhall Corsa won't start, lights/radio working fine

Tags: battery, starter, vauxhall, corsa

I have a 1.2L Petrol 2008 Corsa that won't start.

For the last couple of months the battery light would start flashing once every couple of weeks when starting the engine. I don't do long trips often, it takes me 10-15 minutes to get to work so I thought that the battery just doesn't get the chance to charge up properly. After a longer drive it would stop flashing when starting the engine, so I thought it was fine.

It was happening again this weekend, but this time the engine wouldn't turn on. On the first couple of tries it made a sound like it was trying to turn on, but now it's just completely silent. Electronics in the car work perfectly fine, I can turn the radio on, the headlights, etc. When I try to turn the engine on, the lights on the dashboard light up. If I leave the key in this position for a couple of seconds, the service light starts flashing.

I have tried jump starting the car, it didn't seem to help at all, still no sound coming from the engine. I also rolled it down a hill and tried starting, but still nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a standard shift car? When you say it "does nothing", you're saying no clicking or anything when you twist the key over? What is the resting voltage of the battery (without lights on or key to the on position)?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦, sorry it's 1.2L Manual petrol. Yes, it makes no sound at all when I try to do it now. I did hear it try the first couple of time, but now there's absolutely nothing. Sorry, I don't have the equipment to test the voltage?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your battery is dead and gone due to internal corrosion. I is not unusual for it to still be able to provide the electronics with some power, but it can´t deliver the 100+ amps needed for the starter motor.

Get a new battery. Make sure you do not have it standing around in a discharged state on a regular basis. A battery corrodes much faster when discharged. If you drive only short distance or often not move your car for some weeks, think about getting an external charger/battery tender.

Edit: I see that jump-starting did not work. It *could* be an internal short in the battery. Remove the cable to positive pole and try to jump-start again. If still nothing happens, you have a problem with the Starter-motor / the magnetic switch.

First make sure you get the ignition signal of +12v on the magnetic switch, if you turn the ignition. (should be a black/red cable )

Then check if the motor grounding cable is intact.

If both is ok, it´s probably it´s the switch / starter-motor. Sometimes you can get the switch to work again, by tapping it with a hammer - but that is only a temporary fix. You need to replace one or both parts.

Comment: Thanks, if I charge the current one overnight and it works in the morning is it definitely the battery's fault then? This is what I'm planning to do tonight.

Comment: Sorry ... last part in your op about not being able to jump start dos hint to another problem.
But if it where a corroded battery, charging would not help much, as it cant hold the charge!